# I can no longer open or download apps on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

A couple of weeks ago my iPhone froze while I was using Facebook.  I was able to get it unfrozen but now the Facebook app is gone and I cannot re-download it or any other apps.  Some of the other apps I have, I can't open. I also can't search for anything in the App Store.

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: Have you done a hard reset on your iphone?

Comment: Which iPhone model? iOS version?

Comment: Have you tried 1) restarting your phone 2) logging out of App Store and logging back in?  Do you only use a single App Store? Or do you switch to other regions sometimes?  Is your phone running stock iOS? Which version?  Not jail broken correct?